# How to pull value while looping thru a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I am looping thru and would like to pull the value from a column in each row.  How do I do that?

```
    $('#buildingList tr').each(function () {
        //check each column in the row and get value from column 3 which is a drop down
    });    

<table id="buildingList"> 
<tr> 
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2">
<select id="ddl">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr>  
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2">
<select id="ddl">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2"/> 
<td class="ms-vb2">
<select id="ddl">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: All select elements have the same ID (ddl). That is invalid ;)

Comment: Something to note is that your selects all have the same id attribute. The id attribute should be unique for each element. Maybe your intent is to call each class="ddl"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) option and work with the element's value in your [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) loop:

```
$('#buildingList td select option:selected').each(function(i, el) {
    // Do something with $(el).val() or el.value
});
```

Comment: so this will check all the columns?

Comment: @user54197 -- yes, it is checking all the columns -- you can use `:eq` selector on the `td` if you only want particular columns.  See: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: you are missing the tr inside your selector

Comment: @K Ivanov -- the `tr` is not necessary (actually, the `select`, `td` and `option` are not necessary either.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buildingList tr td:nth-child(3) select option:selected').each(function () {
    var myValue = $(this).text();
});
```

edited for consolidated version

Comment: so this will check all the columns?

Comment: ignores any td's, goes straight for the select tag

Comment: if you want the 3rd column just add td:nth-child(3) like that: $('#buildingList tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with the values. If you want to store them in an array you can do it by:

```
var values = [];
$('#buildingList tr select').each(function (index, elem) {
    values.push(elem.value);
});
```

Also on a side note. You have multiple `<select>` element's with the same ID. An id-attribute should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the drop downs in the 3rd column of each row using:

```
$('#buildingList tr td:eq(2) select').each(function () {    
  var dropDown = $(this); //this refers to the DOM Select
});
```